Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'package' not found
After the flutter update (3.27.1) I am facing IOS errors whenever trying to add new packages.
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'firebase_messaging' not found
/Users/bensal/AndroidStudioProjects/feedec/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:29:8

It is not a cache issue and is not solved using flutter clean or reinstalling pod

Please feel free report issue on their github site : https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues or you can delete podFile.lock file and then try to do pod install and check
